# Which one is faster to process? Print columns with Awk or Cut?

Tags: unix, awk

I have about 100 million rows and 6 fields separated by a space, each field has seven-digit numbers.

I like to delete the 2nd field and can achieve it with the following

```
1. awk '{print $1,$3,$4,$5,$6}' input.txt

2. cut --delimiter=' ' --fields=1,3-6 input.txt
```

Which one is faster to have the desired output? Is there a way to time the process?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a way to time the process?

Yes. Just prepend the command `time` before your code and it will return how long it took. Do it for each one.

```
time awk '{print $1,$3,$4,$5,$6}' input.txt
time cut --delimiter=' ' --fields=1,3-6 input.txt
```

With a quick bit of profiling it looks like `cut` just barely wins out in this scenario. It's still quite an impressive time for `awk` considering how much more capable it is over `cut`.

#### cut

```
$ time for i in {1..1000}; do cut --delimiter=' ' --fields=1,3-6 >/dev/null <<<"one two three four five six seven"; done

real    0m4.074s
user    0m0.496s
sys     0m2.799s
```

#### awk

```
$ time for i in {1..1000}; do awk '{print $1,$3,$4,$5,$6}' >/dev/null <<<"one two three four five six seven"; done

real    0m4.511s
user    0m0.728s
sys     0m3.165s
```

Comment: use head -10000 input.txt > input10000.txt for shorter test file

Comment: Will "cut" be able to hold on under different scenarios? What are the dependent parameters here?

Comment: This shows how to use `time`, but not in the best way. The loop overhead and startup times of the utilities may overshadow differences in the speed of the actually utility (though that information is certainly not completely lost). It would be better to generate a large test file once and run the timing comparisons without loops.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson if all you're interested is relative differences, this shouldn't matter as long as both tests have the same overhead.

Comment: But the startup times of two utilities can be different even if the loop overhead is the same. If you're doing startup 1000 times in a test versus once in actual use, it could give misleading results.

Answer (score 5):

I´ve tested it, and the result is:

> **AWK IS FASTER**

I did my testing with a ~2Million rows file:

It´s just a cut with a standar delimiter, and printing to a file.

As you can see, AWK is ~3X faster in this case  (try yourself the same)

**Demonstration:**

```
# wc -l prueba
2088036 prueba    
# cat test.sh
date +%s
awk '{print $2}' prueba > ok
date +%s
cut -d" " -f2 prueba > ok2
date +%s
# ./test.sh
1484848197
1484848199
1484848204
```

Here you have some docs about the reasons that make awk faster:

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/which-one-is-efficient-cut-cmd-or-using-awk-783673/

https://lyness.io/the-functional-and-performance-differences-of-sed-awk-and-other-unix-parsing-utilities

Hope it helps